Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения в определённый топик в телеграме?
Вместо chat_id (general) нужно направить сообщение в конкретный топик  (message_thread_id).
Как правильно это сделать в данном куске кода? Потому, что во всем коде chat_id встречается именно в этом месте и все.
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def moderate(call):
    load_advert()
    if call.data.startswith("Approve"):
        index = call.data[7:]
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=config.moderator_chat_id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='ППППППППППППППППП')
        if len(advert_dict[index].photo) > 0:
            bot.send_media_group(config.chat_id, advert_dict[index].photo)
        else:
            bot.send_message(config.chat_id, advert_dict[index].description)
        bot.send_message(advert_dict[index].author_chat_id, "аааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааааа")
        del advert_dict[index]

token = '...'
moderator_chat_id = '...'
chat_id = '...'


Если я правильно помню, все сообщения в топиках в ТГ, технически являются ответами на "изначальное" сообщение. Попробуйте найти сообщение стартующее топик и отвечать на него
